# C++ Namespace Warning - Declaration hides global declaration VS 2015 Warning C4459

Tags: c++, namespaces

Why does C++ namespace complain about the following code?

I figured everything within the namespace would be protected from external variables?

**Generates C4459 Warning**

```
int foo = 0;

namespace ns_protected {

  void function ()
  {
    int foo; //Generates C4459 Warning declaration of foo hides global declaration 
  }

}//end ns_protected
```

**NO Warning with code below** If I remove the function

```
int foo = 0;

namespace ns_protected {

  int foo; //NO C4459 Warning Generated by VS 2015 C++
  

}//end ns_protected
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is not caused by the namespace. The following code generates the same warning:

```
int foo = 0;
void function ()
{
  int foo; //Generates C4459 Warning declaration of foo hides global declaration 
}
```

This warning is because the variable "foo" inside the function hides the variable "foo" outside the function.

Comment: The code is automatically generated for Oracle Pro*C
 
I defined the namespace but due to the external variable  and internal local variable foo is also a auto generated variable as well.
 
I was hoping the inner variable would be contained within the namespace

Answer (score 0):

Warnings are not part of the standardized language, but a hint by  your compiler vendor from their expert perspective of what things tend to go wrong.  They warn that they detected a *possible* problem, but even if you *know* you're ok, it's best to change your code to not cause them.

You are right, that is an inconsistency, but hiding variables with scoped local names is responsible for many bugs.  Some costly in terms of damage caused before they were caught.  If this warning helps prevent mistakes, then it is a win.  It may be that the code implementing the warning for functions is a different logical path than the code doing static analysis on namespace scoped variables, and it's just an oversight.

To address this issue, from best to worst way:

1. Good: do not have global (or nested namespace-scoped) variables.
2. Good: choose non-hiding local variable names.
3. Bad: disable the warning.
4. Terrible: ignore the compiler output and pretend it's not there

#3 is bad for the reason the warning exists at all: it could be a problem, and historically has been enough times for others that it's worth warning you before it becomes your problem too.  Benefit from others' mistakes without having to go through the pain first, by trusting that it's oftentimes a bug.

Ignoring compiler output is terrible, because it trains people to not read the compiler output, and some real bugs may be emitted in warnings.  Treat each one seriously, and do not allow them to exist in your code.  Any time it warns, think long and hard before fixing it, too.  You are likely "near" a bug, and a quick change may mask it rather than fix it.